# Oшибка конвертации типов объектов класса

Tags: c++, классы, методы

Коллеги,

программа, написанная по урокам не компилируется.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

class Person
{
int age;
string name;
string surname;

public:
void dataChange (int y, string m_name, string m_surname)
{
    age=y;
    name=m_name;
    surname=m_surname;
}

void print()
{
    cout<< "My name is "<<name<<" "<<surname<<" and I am "<<age<< " years 
old"<<endl;
}
};

int main()
{
Person me = ( 28, "Stepan", "Sokol");
me.print();
me.dataChange(27, "Esteban", "Falke");
me.print();

getchar();
return 0;
}
```

Выдаются ошибки на строчке объявления переменной me класса Person:

Error   1   error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'const char [6]' to 'Person'  c:\users\u20y36\desktop\progs\project2\project2\source.cpp  32  1   Project2

2   IntelliSense: no suitable constructor exists to convert from "const char [6]" to "Person"   c:\Users\u20y36\Desktop\Progs\Project2\Project2\Source.cpp  32  14  Project2

В чем проблема? Благодарю.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас какие-то странные строки

```
Person me = ( 28, "Stepan", "Sokol");
me.print();
me.dataChange(27, "Esteban", "Falke");
me.print();
```

Скорее всего подразумевалось

```
Person me;
me.dataChange(28, "Stepan", "Sokol");
me.print();
me.dataChange(27, "Esteban", "Falke");
me.print();
```

инициализация сразу возможна если реализуете конструктор с аргументами

```
public:
Person(int age, string name, string surname)
{
    this.age=age;
    this.name=name;
    this.surname=surname;
}
```

Тогда можно будет написать

```
Person me(28, "Stepan", "Sokol");
```

Comment: Заработало без new Person().

Но разве я не могу инициализировать me сразу?

Comment: Вы наверное язык перепутали, в c++ `Person me = new Person();` вызовет ошибку компиляции.

Comment: @VTT, да, точно

Comment: Благодарю! То что надо

Answer (score 1):

Для инициализации объекта следует определить соответствующий конструктор:

```
public: explicit Person(int const initial_age, char const * const psz_name, char const * const psz_surname)
:   age{initial_age}, name{psz_name}, surname{psz_surname}
{}
```

тогда его можно будет вызвать так:

```
Person me{28, "Stepan", "Sokol"};
```

Comment: Благодарю! То что надо